# Stop clothes from twisting but not turning

Tags: armature, parent

This sounds strange, but when I parent armatures to clothes with automatic weights, they twist and turn with it.

Yes, I am fully aware that is the whole point of parenting the clothes to armatures in the first place.

Is there any way to limit how far clothes could twist or turn, if at all?

Comment: Usually you can make armature's bones more or less influent on parented mesh assigning weights (you can paint weights in object weight mode). This should work in this case too, afaik. Did you try and is not working or are you looking for something different?

Comment: That results in pieces not moving at all, especially while they are proxied via ManuelLab. The meshes usually fall apart when given cloth physics, which I am also trying to resolve. That much seems to need tougher cloth physics itself.